# Unable to load the map

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, ros-melodic, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i run this command:roslaunch turtlebot3_navigation turtlebot3_navigation.launch map_file:=/home/kannan/catkin_ws/src/tb3_house_map/tb3_house_map.pgm
im receiving following error

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

```
process[robot_state_publisher-1]: started with pid [12206]
process[map_server-2]: started with pid [12207]
process[amcl-3]: started with pid [12208]
process[move_base-4]: started with pid [12209]
process[rviz-5]: started with pid [12210]
[ WARN] [1631790491.023845153]: Request for map failed; trying again...
[map_server-2] process has died [pid 12207, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/melodic/lib/map_server/map_server /home/kannan/catkin_ws/src/tb3_house_map/tb3_house_map.pgm __name:=map_server __log:=/home/kannan/.ros/log/4065906e-16de-11ec-9f55-e82a44ef4c23/map_server-2.log].
log file: /home/kannan/.ros/log/4065906e-16de-11ec-9f55-e82a44ef4c23/map_server-2*.log
[ WARN] [1631790491.760930025, 35.489000000]: Request for map failed; trying again...
[ WARN] [1631790492.476759739, 35.989000000]: Request for map failed; trying again...
[ WARN] [1631790493.181477336, 36.490000000]: Request for map failed; trying again...
[ WARN] [1631790493.890477452, 36.992000000]: Request for map failed; trying again...
[ WARN] [1631790494.574137869, 37.492000000]: Request for map failed; trying again...
[ WARN] [1631790495.275269778, 37.993000000]: Request for map failed; trying again...
[ WARN] [1631790495.970947694, 38.494000000]: Request for map failed; trying again...
[ WARN] [1631790496.685223565, 38.995000000]: Request for map failed; trying again...
[ WARN] [1631790497.441300666, 39.496000000]: Request for map failed; trying again...
[ WARN] [1631790498.189197946, 39.988000000]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: canTransform: target_frame map does not exist.. canTransform returned after 0.1 timeout was 0.1.
[ WARN] [1631790498.208710466, 39.997000000]: Request for map failed; trying again...
[ WARN] [1631790498.974576219, 40.497000000]: Request for map failed; trying again...
[ WARN] [1631790499.757871814, 40.998000000]: Request for map failed; trying again...
[ WARN] [1631790500.514945113, 41.499000000]: Request for map failed; trying again...
[ WARN] [1631790501.283303952, 42.000000000]: Request for map failed; trying again...
[ WARN] [1631790502.059915692, 42.500000000]: Request for map failed; trying again...
[ WARN] [1631790502.807176332, 43.001000000]: Request for map failed; trying again...
[ WARN] [1631790503.573868822, 43.502000000]: Request for map failed; trying again...
[ WARN] [1631790504.336607227, 44.002000000]: Request for map failed; trying again...
[ WARN] [1631790505.079645306, 44.503000000]: Request for map failed; trying again...
[ WARN] [1631790505.726019180, 44.998000000]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: canTransform: target_frame map does not exist.. canTransform returned after 0.1 timeout was 0.1.
[ WARN] [1631790505.733022720, 45.005000000]: Request for map failed; trying again...
[ WARN] [1631790506.488765638, 45.506000000]: Request for map failed; trying again...
[ WARN] [1631790507.236729152, 46.006000000]: Request for map failed; trying again...
[ WARN] [1631790507.996685381, 46.506000000]: Request for map failed; trying again...
[ WARN] [1631790508.746365539, 47.007000000]: Request for map failed; trying again...
[ WARN] [1631790509.486753942, 47.507000000]: Request for map failed; trying again...
[ WARN] [1631790510.246844009, 48.008000000]: Request for map failed; trying again...
[ WARN] [1631790511.016623846, 48.509000000]: Request for map failed; trying again...
[ WARN] [1631790511.797584221, 49.010000000]: Request for map failed; trying again...
[ WARN] [1631790512.533934996, 49.511000000]: Request for map failed; trying again...
[ WARN] [1631790513.286004662, 50.006000000]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: canTransform: target_frame map does not exist.. canTransform returned after 0.1 timeout was 0.1.
[ WARN] [1631790513.297725943, 50.012000000]: Request for map failed; trying again...
[ WARN] [1631790514.030659744, 50.512000000]: Request for map failed; trying again...
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/386659/unable-to-load-the-map/) by [vidu98](https://answers.ros.org/users/84866/vidu98/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2021-09-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-09-16**:
Can you show the `log` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `map_file` of `map_server` should not be an image file, but a configuration file (yaml file).
For the contents of the configuration file, please refer to [here](http://wiki.ros.org/map_server#YAML_format) first.

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2021-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vidu98](https://answers.ros.org/users/84866/vidu98/) on 2021-09-17**:
Thanks a lot, I understood the mistake.